# Как обернуть все значки ActionColumn в обертку?

Tags: php, yii2, gridview

У `GridView` есть `ActionColumn` в котором рисуются значки и ссылки. Мне нужно, чтобы все ссылки были обёрнуты в `div` с каким нибудь классом. Как это сделать?

Я унаследовал и то и то от дефолтных, чтоб можно было что-то менять, но что и где менять или добавить - я не знаю. Всякие `$contentOptions`, `$buttonOptions`, `$headerOptions` - это не то. Потому что там определяются опции непосредственно на колонку в целом или ячейку `td`, например добавляет класс к ячейке, а нужно именно вставить туда `div`  с классом

Answer (score 0):

Решил переопределением метода `renderDataCell`:

```
public function renderDataCell($model, $key, $index) {
    if ($this->contentOptions instanceof Closure) {
        $options = call_user_func($this->contentOptions, $model, $key, $index, $this);
    } else {
        $options = $this->contentOptions;
    }

    return Html::tag('td', Html::tag('div', $this->renderDataCellContent($model, $key, $index), ['class' => 'my-class-for-inner-div']), $options);
}
```